# Google search result adding language in the URL

Tags: sxa

We have added `languageEmbedding : never` in our Sitecore SXA site. We are not getting language in the URL when we open site directly.

However, when we are searching any result on google and redirect that page from search result then it is showing the languages in the URL.

Https://example.com/en/testpage

Could someone assist me why this is happening?
We do not want to show language in the URL after searching in google search.

Updated : It's happening only on google search. Other browser such as bing and yahoo are showing the correct results without adding language in the url.

Comment: can you check in show config file is anything is overrided

Answer (score 0):

Two things to look at.

- The `canonical url` on your pages.
- What is in Sitemap.XML

Without knowing more about your solution, it's not really possible to point you in a more specific direction.

Comment: we are not using any canonical url and Site map.xml in our site.

Comment: I have just checked related to site map.xml file on browser. It is creating , by default and it is showing url without em bedding language there.